# force nginx to rewrite 403 response with document

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to rewrite 403 response that already has document from app. And use my document or just plain text response instead of detailed application data.

I tried doing :
 `error_page 403 /40x.html; location = /40x.html { }`

but since document is already served by app, error_page doesn't work.

Comment: I found out that the main problem was  headers.
I tried to change them by add_header instead of default_header.

Answer (score 0):

I was lacking the:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

option in server config.

After adding it and modifying default_headers it started working as desired